# Rstudioによるパネルデータ作成について

Tags: r

（従属変数）
A：１人あたりのゴミ排出量（日/g）
（説明変数）
a:人口 b:人口密度 c:平均世帯人員    d:核家族率　e:公営借家率  f:民営借家率
g:１人あたりの住宅延べ面積(㎡)   h:対可住地農用地割合 i:対可住地宅地割合　
j:財政力指数 k:１００人当たりの事業所数  l:農林漁業事業所数 m:鉱業事業所数
n:卸売・小売業・飲食店事業所割合    o:サービス業事業所割合   p:ごみ分別区分数
q:可燃ごみ収集回数(回/週) r:不燃ごみ収集回収数（回/月）

1:直接焼却率 2:直接埋立率 3:粗大ごみ処理施設処理率 4:資源化施設処理率
5:直接資源化率 6:ごみ分別区分数  7:１人当たり集団回収数（g/日） 8:リサイクル率（％）

としてパネルデータ分析を行いたいです。
空白はあるものの２年分のデータは揃っています。

どんな関数を使えばいいか等、教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)
```

から始めましょう